# I install oracle client 11g on my machine .I am not give any username and password of course I am not get that window at initialisation time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How connect to the db .I am tried with the following username and passwords system/manager ,scott/tiger etc .But no luck I am still not connected to the db.And also I am getting TNS:Protocol adapter error. I am not understanding why? I also gone through the services for start/restart But there is no  at least one single Oracle service file.How I am getting this oracle services as well as how I connect to the db.Please some body help me. My system operating system windows XP.. I am installing oracle client 11g on windows Xp operating system.

Comment: I am getting The following errors...1)TNS::Protocol adapter error.                          2)TNs:ORA:12541: no listener when i am connecting like this >conn sys/pwd@orcl.                                                                                                         3)Tns:could not resolve the connect identifier specified sqlplus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you want to connect dbserver from dbclient we must know the username and password.That are all knows to the who install the Database server not Database client. From where ever we want to connect to the db we must and should know the username and password .i.e either  from dbserver or dbclient.IN OTHER words when installing oracle client we don't enter any username and passwords.Because in client there is no database .we just connect the server db only.The password and username knows whose install DB server not client.From client we connect the server by using server username and server passwords...

Answer (score 0):

Oracle client is software that allows a remote computer to talk to Oracle. If you were to write a piece of software that communicated with the database, you would use the Oracle Client to facilitate that communication.

If you need oracle database in your machine you can go for Oracle database version like Express edition and Enterprise, standard edition. You can't create any database using the oracle client software.

Note : While installing oracle client(any version) it won't ask any username and password.

Steps to connect Oracle client to Oracle database

Consider your oracle server tnsname like below

```
ORA11 =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = ORA11)
 )
)
```

Place above tnsname text into your tnsname.ora file (C:\app\oracle\product\network/admin/tnsnames.ora)

After that check your sql*plus prompt like

```
tnsping databasename
```

sample output

```
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=gracelan)
(PORT=1525)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SID=GRA901m)))
OK (80 msec)

connect username/password@dbname
```

Comment: Thank u for ur replay..I am worked some times before one year  in oracle express.But not on the oracle client . from the Oracle client how i can connect the my company  oracle server..

Comment: First of all let me know for connecting to oracle server from the oracle client there required any username and passwords.If yes how i am get that all

Comment: Pls give me replay i am waiting your replay.

Comment: check your tnsname.ora file in your oracle installed path after that place your company oracle database server name into that file.

For example :
ORA11 =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = ORA11)
 )
)

Comment: I have already two service names in tnsnames.ora file ...sorry for this                       where i am give this cmd tnsping data basename...I am tried as fallows          start-->run ---->tnsping databasename.I am getting one window in that ALL RIGHTS RECEIVED.IT will  display  3-5 seconds ..After that automatically closed that window

Comment: Can you please tell me the oracle server version?

Comment: when i am connecting  using this  system/admin@orcl    .............System is    i am entered in user name place at the time of creating service name and pwd also like that ..ORCL is the service name.

Comment: start-> run -> cmd -> tnsping <serverhostname>


Can you please tell me the oracle server version?. If it's 11g you can't able to access sys user in client machine. try with some other user to access your oracle server.

Comment: Sorry in i don't  know  oracle server version?.During the server is in control of DBA

Comment: how we connect with the oracle db from the oracle client . In oracle express edition  we connect by using username/pwd.But here in oracle client how we can connect

Answer (score 0):

[image]

can you please provide your tnsname ping output.

Use your server Name like `tnsping orcl` in cmd.exe

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\user>tnsping orcl

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 08-OCT-2
015 15:26:57

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\app\user\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.us.oracle
.com)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: In your output Host should be in your server host name. If possible could you please share your tnsname?

(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)

One more thing, do you have oracle PL/SQL developer tool in your machine?

Comment: # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\user\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORADMT =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = oradmt.us.oracle.com)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.us.oracle.com)
    )
  )

Comment: Bro first tell me how we connect with the db from the oracle client..REquire any password/user names or some tnsname.In above all the tnsnames in my machine

Comment: Here your local machine has been pointing to as a server. So only you're getting No listener error.
Ask your DBA to send correct tnsname text with exact server name

Comment: pl/sql tool is where in this package   or some separate tool

Comment: okk today my dba is in leave..when he come back i am asking....                           one more  thing sql>conn system/system  it shows error TNS:Protocol adapter error.......................                                                                       When i am connecting sql>conn system/system@orcl .It PROVIDES TNS;NO LISTENER                                                                                        WHEN I AM CONNECTING in some other way i am getting could not resolve the connect identifier specified sqlplus..

Comment: We can download pl/sql developer in oracle website, it's freeware only.http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index-097090.html while installing oracle 11g itself tool will install. check your installed oracle packages it has

Comment: I want to know how do you received above mentioned tnsname text?

Comment: i am created above two tnsnames with some data like username/pwd and service name etc

Comment: Don't do like that. Because you are using oracle client, so you need to know exact service name and server name. Then only you have to create tnsname file in your local. Otherwise always touch with your respective DBA. Connecting database is not an big issue :)

Comment: There is three parts we need to know exactly then only we can able to connect server. 

1. HOST = 127.0.0.1 (your server id address or machine name)
2. PORT = 15213
3. SERVICE_NAME = ORA11 (Oracle server service name which they maintained in your company)

Comment: What's wrong with that i am created in what u said.But now u saying like this i am not understanding..ORA11 =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = ORA11)
 )
)                                                                                                                         After  installing i am created that two tnsservicenames. By selecting one file from the oracle client.That displays some screen shots i am gone through that only ..

Comment: I think i am not disturb that host =localhost port -1521 and oradmti this is copied from the some browser that's all. BAla

Comment: Pls tell me for connecting oracle server with the oracle client.i.e mean oracle server username/password  (or) tnsservername created username and password